# Does Akka-Http supports request scope state/implicits?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using Scala and Akka-Http in my project. I wanted to ask if there is functionality in Akka to hold separate state per each incoming request scope and to be accessible from any place (as direct call or implicit).

For example:

My akka-http server receives HTTP GET request and handles it in routes. I would like to extract request token from HttpHeader and use it much later in some methods/other request. Right now I just extract token in routes and pass it to each method I need (sometimes a few levels down).

I am wondering if there is a way to simplify it to somehow extract said token exactly where I need it instead of passing it through all methods (token is just an example, it could be anything from request context). Since (at least I think so, correct me if I am wrong) each request in akka-http is handled separately maybe it is possible?

Thanks for any suggestions and responses :)

Comment: You basically wants to have a context created from a request and propagate it in the downstream code "implicitly", right?

Comment: @GaëlJ Kind of, yeah. I would rather avoid implementing this logic myself if its achievable somehow in Akka

Comment: I'm not familiar with Akka Http. But you probably won't get 1'y answer on SO for such a question: you'll have to search by yourself and if some code you find is not working, SO will help you ;)